# Move a custom array item up or down

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

I want to move a custom array item up and down using `Collections.swap`, but I don't understand how to implement it in a way so that my app doesn't crash.

```
private List<Drinks> myDrinks = new ArrayList<Drinks>(); 
private ArrayList<String> yourItems;
```

...

```
 private void populateDrinkList() {

        if (yourItems.contains("pie")){
         myDrinks.add(new Drinks("a"));
         myDrinks.add(new Drinks("b"));
         myDrinks.add(new Drinks("c"));
         myDrinks.add(new Drinks("d"));
         myDrinks.add(new Drinks("e"));

         if (yourItems.contains("chocolate")){
            String toMoveUp = "e";
             while (myDrinks.indexOf(toMoveUp) != 0) {
            int i = myDrinks.indexOf(toMoveUp);
            Collections.swap(myDrinks, i, i - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you explain with example how you would like the ouput and input of your code

Comment: So whats the problem?

Comment: I want to change the position of the array items. For example, if my other array contains the  value chocolate(yourItems) I want to move the position of the, myDrinks, value to be prioritized. If you have chocolate you are more likely to make recipe e

Comment: This should work fine. What errors you are getting?

Comment: It doesn't work because the List type is custom not String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Fix  `yourItems` variable `ArrayList` it should be declared in that way:

```
private ArrayList<String> yourItems=new ArrayList<String>();
```

Second point `myDrinks` is an `ArrayList` Collection that takes `Drinks` Object as Parameter which means you cannot use String toMoveup to look inside it instead it should be a `Drinks` Object:

```
Drinks toMoveUp=new Drinks("e");
```

And then:

```
while (myDrinks.indexOf(toMoveUp) != 0) {
            int i = myDrinks.indexOf(toMoveUp);
            Collections.swap(myDrinks, i, i - 1);
    }
```

Good Luck

Comment: it crashes when I have 2 selected. This Array is corresponding to a list view. Are list view objects static once they are placed?

Comment: when you have 2 data selected ?

Comment: definitely it would crash cause when you select more than one data it becomes an array and this function is not adapted to it

Comment: How could I make it not crash? If I have (yourItems.contains("Gin")) [show all drinks for gin] + (yourItems.contains("Vodka")) [show all drinks for vodka] THEN move the drinks that contain both to the top of the list.

Comment: ask another question in another thread we cant solve it through comments

Answer (score -1):

You can remove it from list (giving the index you already got), and then use `myDrinks.add(0,<Object>)` method to add it as the 0th element. The code would be,

```
        Drinks toMoveUp = new Drinks("e");
        int index = myDrinks.indexOf(toMoveUp);
        myDrinks.remove(index);  //remove from where it is now
        myDrinks.add(0,toMoveUp); //add to the top
```

Comment: I don't want to delete the other values. using swap would move all the other values down

Comment: There is already a method available to do this. [Collections.swap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap(java.util.List, int, int))

Comment: @VimalBera, Swap would bring the element at top to the place where the `toMoveUp` is, but this would only bring that `toMoveUp` element up

Comment: @user3127974, Edited answer to be more clear. The item deleted is added back to the top.